# How to insert a image in word document with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have this code:

```
public class ImageAttachmentInDocument {
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws InvalidFormatException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();   
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("encabezado.jpg");
        doc.addPictureData(IOUtils.toByteArray(is), doc.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);


        XWPFParagraph title = doc.createParagraph();    
        XWPFRun run = title.createRun();
        run.setText("Fig.1 A Natural Scene");
        run.setBold(true);
        title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test4.docx");
        doc.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();        
    }
}
```

(I am using Apache POI 3.11 and xmlbeans-2.3.0 in eclipse IDE)

when I generate the document, the image is not displayed

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15):

You don't seem to be attaching the image to the text where you want it shown!

Taking inspiration from the [XWPF Simple Images Example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xwpf/usermodel/SimpleImages.java), I think what you'd want your code to be is:

```
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

    XWPFParagraph title = doc.createParagraph();    
    XWPFRun run = title.createRun();
    run.setText("Fig.1 A Natural Scene");
    run.setBold(true);
    title.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    String imgFile = "encabezado.jpg";
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
    run.addBreak();
    run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, imgFile, Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(200)); // 200x200 pixels
    is.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test4.docx");
    doc.write(fos);
    fos.close();
```

The difference there is that rather than explicitly attaching the image to the document, you instead add it to a run. The run add also adds it to the document, but importantly also sets things up to reference the picture from the run you want it to show in

Comment: This works quite well for me. Thank you so much.