# Can i take a screenshot and paste it in a word file in appium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I'm currently using the below method to take screenshots and store them in a folder called 'Screenshots'. But what i want is, to take these screenshots and paste them in a word document according to the test cases to which they belong.
Is it possible? If so could somebody please guide me?

```
public  String FailureScreenshotAndroid(String name) {
            try {
                Date d = new Date();
                String date = d.toString().replace(":", "_").replace(" ", "_");
                TakesScreenshot t = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
                File f1 = t.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);//Temporary Location
                String permanentLocation =System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\Screenshots\\"+name+date+".png";
                File f2 = new File(permanentLocation);
                FileUtils.copyFile(f1, f2);
                return permanentLocation;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                String msg = e.getMessage();
                return msg;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You probably need to use something like "Apache POI Word" to either create a word file or change an old one. Next you can add your image there.

Comment: @Mike_Jr If you have any sample code for the same, that would be great. If not, still appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take screenshots and paste it in a word file one by one using webDriver (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877185/how-to-take-screenshots-and-paste-it-in-a-word-file-one-by-one-using-webdriver)

Comment: @KopreshPujari Pretty much what was done in the link above this comment. 

Save your image like you are doing now. 
Add it to your word file like in here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26769168/7176949
Then delete the image from your harddrive

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class TakeScreenshots {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFRun run = docx.createParagraph().createRun();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/xyz/doc1.docx");

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= 5; counter++) {
                captureScreenShot(docx, run, out);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }

            docx.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            docx.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void captureScreenShot(XWPFDocument docx, XWPFRun run, FileOutputStream out) throws Exception {

        String screenshot_name = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
        BufferedImage image = new Robot()
                .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        File file = new File("d:/xyz/" + screenshot_name);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        InputStream pic = new FileInputStream("d:/xyz/" + screenshot_name);
        run.addBreak();
        run.addPicture(pic, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, screenshot_name, Units.toEMU(350), Units.toEMU(350));
        pic.close();
        file.delete();
    }

}
```